# How can I change the version of Bolt protocol that is used in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Memgraph supports both Bolt v4 and Bolt v5. Is there a way to use one or another version of Bolt protocol? Is there a configuration setting that can force a certain version of the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

To use different versions of Bolt, just use different client versions installed via e.g. `pip`, server and client have an automatic resolution of which version is going to be used (based on client version and what server supports). There is no specific flag or setting in Memgraph.